# VIM - unknown function: pythoncomplete#Complete

Tags: python, vim, omnicomplete

when I type the following code in a .py - file:

```
import numpy
numpy.
```

and then press the TAB key which triggers Omnicompletion, I get the following error:

```
Error: Required vim compiled with +python
E117: Unknown function: pythoncomplete#Complete
```

However, when I type `vim --version | grep python`, I get:

```
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python/dyn      +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      +python3/dyn     +vreplace
```

Can someone explain this behaviour or does someone have any ideas where to dig? There is a similar question on stackoverflow, but in that case VIM was compiled without python support.

Comment: Try `setlocal omnifunc=python3complete#Complete` with `VimCompletesMe` plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Check again from within Vim with

```
:echo has('python')
```

It may be that even though your Vim has been compiled with Python, the dynamic loading of the Python interpreter fails, usually because the corresponding shared library cannot be found. You find its name in the `:version` output under `Compilation:`

Comment: `:echo has('python')` returns 1, so this doesn't seem to be the issue here

Comment: Interesting; that's exactly the check inside `autoload/pythoncomplete.vim`, and (based on your error), it seems to return `0` there.

Comment: Between my question and my comment, I had installed YouCompleteMe. I just found that when removing YouCompleteMe, `has('python')` returns zero, and when adding YouCompleteMe again, `has('python')` returns one again. Also, after installing YCM, I can enter `:call pythoncomplete#Complete()` and no longer get the "unknown function" error (instead I get "not enough arguments") and I can successfully OmniComplete by typing Ctrl+x and Ctrl+o (as TAB is used by YCM now).

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, your vim is compiled with dynamic support for both python versions ( python3/dyn and python/dyn ). There is one thing you should keep in mind in this setup:
The command `has('python')` and `has('python3')` already invokes the usage of this specific python version **exclusively**.
So apparently, YCM invokes `has('python')` before `has('python3')`, so that python3 becomes active and python2 inactive for the rest of the vim-session. `pythoncomplete#Complete` somehow only works with python2.
So you could fix pythoncomplete#Complete by explicitly invoking python2 at the very top of your vimrc:

```
set nocompatible
if has('python') " if dynamic py|py3, this line already activates python2.                                                                                                                     
  let s:python_version = 2                                                                                                                                                                                         
elseif has('python3')                                                                                                                                                                                              
  let s:python_version = 3                                                                                                                                                                                         
else                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  let s:python_version = 0                                                                                                                                                                                         
endif
echomsg 'Using python'.s:python_version
```

In the rest of your vimrc you can check for python version with `s:python_version`, if you dont need it, the `has` commands already to the job.

Answer (score 0):

You might need both python2 & 3 as in my case

`let g:python3_host_prog='C:/Bin/Miniconda3/python.exe'
let g:python_host_prog='C:/Bin/miniconda2/python.exe'`

:echo has('python') returned 0 until I did this.
Need for YCM & ensime & neoterm in my case
Downloaded directly from the neoterm site (windows obviously for this case)